# Python file.read() seeing junk characters at the beginning of a file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to use Python to concatenate a few javascript files together before minifying them, basically like so:

```
outfile = open("output.js", "w")
for somefile in a_list_of_file_names:
    js = open(somefile)
    outfile.write(js.read())
    js.close()
outfile.close()
```

The minifier complains about illegal characters and syntax errors at the beginning of each file, so I did some diagnostics.

```
>>> r = open("output.js")
>>> somestring = r.readline()
>>> somestring
'\xef\xbb\xbfvar $j = jQuery.noConflict(),\n'
>>> print somestring
ï»¿var $j = jQuery.noConflict(),
```

The first line of the file should, of course be "var $j = jQuery.noConflict(),"

In case it makes a difference, I'm working from within Windows.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here's what I'm getting from the minifier:

```
U:\>java -jar c:\path\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar c:\path\somefile.js -o c:\path\bccsminified.js --type js -v

[INFO] Using charset Cp1252

[ERROR] 1:2:illegal character

[ERROR] 1:2:syntax error

[ERROR] 1:3:illegal character
```

Comment: What happens if you `print somefile.readline()` -- do you get the cruft? How about if you open the files in Notepad?

Comment: Yes, 
    print somefile.readline()
generates the same junk. When I open the file in notepad, it displayed the first line in a smaller typeface, for some strange reason. Visual Studio refused to open it. After fiddling with it Notepad no longer displays it odd and Visual Studio opens it, but the minifier still throws errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF BB BF is a Unicode Byte-Order Mark (BOM).  Those are actually in your files.  That's why Python is seeing it.

Either ignore/discard the BOM or reencode the files to omit it.

Comment: You're entirely right. Digging through the YUIcompressor documentation, I found a mention to the --charset flag. Setting it to utf-8 solved my worries.

Answer (score 6):

That's a UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark).  You've probably edited the file with Notepad.